# Find out if PNG is 8 or 24?

Tags: image, encoding, png, bit

Is there a way to find out if a PNG is the 8 or 24 type? Ive tried with windows, fireworks and photoshop but I can't figure this out.
Thanks

Comment: Use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html). It has a somewhat opaque [documentation](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt), but once you get through to `png_read_png()` and `png_get_bit_depth()` and `png_get_channels()`, you have what you need. If you want a command line tool, check out [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) (in particular the `identify` command).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open it in Photoshop and check what's written on the top bar. If it says "index", then it has been saved as 8-bit PNG, if it says "RGB/8" then your PNG is a 32-bit one.
Alternatively you can open Image/Mode menu and for an 8-bit one it would be "Indexed color", while for a 32-bit one - "RGB color".

Another really quick way to tell without opening the file is to see if there is any smooth gradient transparencies in the image. 8 bit pngs don't have transparent gradients - it's either fully opaque or fully transparent (nothing in between).

> (For those who don't have Photoshop)

Howto identify bit depth for image files on Windows:

```
*Right click* image file > Properties > Details > Bit depth
```

[image: Identify image bit depth on Windows]

Comment: just have to say that I love your icon, Dr. Snuggles is a childhood favorite :-)

Comment: i recently found out that they produced some new episodes a few years ago with "new graphics", but as far as i was able to tell the look and feel is similar to the old episodes

Comment: then I learnt something new on SO today ;-) off to google now to locate those episodes!

Comment: (offtopic): now i remember what that was, it was only the trailer i have seen (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ti8nJYmC7W0). no new episodes (none that i found) :(

Comment: But isn't this question about PNG24?

Answer (score 29):

The quickest way is to just peek at bytes 24 and 25 in the PNG file.  They contain the bit depth (1, 2, 4, 8, or 16) and color type

- 0: gray,
- 2: rgb,
- 3: indexed (colormapped),
- 4: gray+alpha, or
- 6: rgba.

If the bitdepth is 8 and the colortype is 3 you have a PNG8, and if the bitdepth is 8 and colortype is 2 you have a PNG24.

On a *nix platform, the "file" command will do this for you, e.g.,

A PNG8:

```
glenn.rp> file logo.png
logo.png: PNG image data, 640 x 480, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

A PNG24:

```
glenn.rp> file rose.png
rose.png: PNG image data, 70 x 46, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I guarantee nearly everyone who got here did so because they wonder how to do it in CODE.

Comment: @tayoung no, this is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

In a Linux based environment, one could use the `file` command.

```
$ file image-1.png

PNG image data, 3840 x 2160, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

So based on the output above, image-1.png has four channels (**RGBA** - red, green, blue, alpha). 8-bit per channel which sums up to **32 bits**.

```
$ file image-2.png

PNG image data, 3840 x 2160, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

image-2.png has only 3 channels (**RGB**). It does not have the alpha channel. So it is in **PNG‑24** format.

There's also `identify` command from ImageMagick that could use to retrieve more detailed information about image files.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
identify -verbose image.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the 'Bit Depth' column and it should show you the Bit depth right in the details view in file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

**This way for Mac Os**

> Right Click > Get Info

My image appears to be 32 bit in total.

Color space: RGB (3 * 8 bit = 24 bit)

Alpha channel: Yes (8 bit)

**Result:**

24 + 8 = 32 bit

[image]