# Find out if PNG is 8 or 24 bits and alpha

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, png

Given a `UIImage`/`NSImage` or `NSData` instance, how do you find out **programatically** if a PNG is 8 bits or 24 bits? And if it has an alpha channel?

Is there any Cocoa/Cocoa Touch API that helps with this?

To avoid duplication, here is the [non-programatic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278159/find-out-if-png-is-8-or-24) to the question, and here's a way to find out [if an image is a PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147311/finding-image-type-from-nsdata-or-uiimage).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000956-CH1g-TPXREF183

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a person who programmed for a long time on a J2ME platform, I know the PNG format very well. If you have the raw data as a `NSData` instance, looking up the information is very easy since the PNG format is very straightforward.

See [PNG Specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Contents.html)

The PNG file starts with a signature and then it contains a sequence of chunks. You are interested only in the first chunk, `IHDR`.

So, the code should be along the lines of:

1. Skip the first 8 bytes (signature)
2. Skip 4 bytes (IHDR chunk length)
3. Skip 4 bytes (IHDR chunk type = "IHDR")
4. Read IHDR

> Width:              4 bytes
>      Height:             4 bytes
>      Bit depth:          1 byte
>      Color type:         1 byte
>      Compression method: 1 byte
>      Filter method:      1 byte
>      Interlace method:   1 byte

For alpha, you should also check if there is a `tRNS` (transparency) chunk in the file. To find a chunk, you can go with the following algorithm:

1. Read chunk length (4 bytes)
2. Read chunk type (4 bytes)
3. Check chunk type whether it is the type we are looking for
4. Skip chunk length bytes
5. Skip 4 bytes of CRC
6. Repeat

**EDIT:**

To find info about a `UIImage` instance, get its `CGImage` and use one of the `CGImageGet...` functions. 
It should be noted that **All** integer values in a PNG file are read in *Big-endian* format.

Comment: +1 Bear in mind that a PNG can implement transparency either by having an alpha channel (you read that in the "Color type" IHDR property) OR, for some image types, by including a tRNS chunk. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569887/libpng-palette-png-with-alpha-or-not/13570973#13570973)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the `CGImage` will have the same properties than the original data?

Comment: @hpique That really depends on how the image is created. I know that the iOS PNG loader could not load some of the unusual PNG formats. I remember implementing my own PNG parser in one ocassion and the `CGImage` created by my implementation definitely had the correct properties :) When speaking about iOS PNG loader, alpha information should be correct, not sure about the bit depth. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251595/iphone-sdk-accessing-indexed-color-png-images for info about paletted PNG images.